# Can I export an imagery directly to a geo-referenced raster form File|Export Map in Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing

While using File|Export to export an imagery to raster, is there a way to have it geo-referenced in a way that if I load the exported raster into the map, the image sits exactly in its place without the need to use georeferencing toolbar/ defining the spatial reference?

Comment: Have you tried using the Write World File option during your Export Map?  That seems to save the correct coordinate values but you will need to use the Properties of the raster file to re-apply its Coordinate System so that they can be interpreted correctly.

Comment: It worked! When I add the raster it sits exactly in its own place. I suppose I just need to define the spatial reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Write World File option during your Export Map.

That saves the correct coordinate values but you will need to use the Properties of the raster file to then re-apply its Coordinate System so that they can be interpreted correctly.